# Objects connections - constraints?

Tags: objects

I am creating module system in blender where user should easily connect objects/collections to each other (not a typical snapping).

I made a script where by clicking one button, all selected objects move and rotate to active one.In general it works fine.

Main elements of that system are multi-object collections. In one collection there is a main object ande some empty objects which are used as a base points to attract other objects.

Now all empty objects are children to main object (parent). When I move main object, all emptys also move, which is good. But when i want to move empty, the rest objects in collection dont move, which is bad. It is a problem, because sometimes i need to select empty and move it with whole collection to another point. There is only empty moving, without rest.

Is there a way to have multi-object collection, where all objects don't move refering to each other ? I tried copy location constraints but it is not working properly when there are constraints on every element. I don't want join objects. I need to have few objects within collection.